# Expander overlay a control in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a tree control where the users can select the nodes by checking them. I want to give the user an option to display the selected items only.

I am thinking of an expander. When the user expands the expander, the expander expands over the original tree control with another content which shows only the selected items.

The trouble is the expander is only stretching to the size of its content. I want the expander  to stretch fully so that the original tree will be invisible until the expander is collapsed.

Code is given below. The tree outside the canvas is the original tree. The tree inside the canvas is the read only tree which the expander is supposed to show

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="33" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <Canvas Canvas.ZIndex="999" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <telerik:RadExpander HorizontalAlignment="Right" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Show Selected Items"
                      ExpandDirection="Down" Expanded="RadExpander_Expanded" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <telerik:RadExpander.Header>
                            <TextBlock
      Text="Selected Items"

      Width="{Binding      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadExpander}, Path=ActualWidth}"   />
                        </telerik:RadExpander.Header>

                        <telerik:RadTreeView IsExpandOnSingleClickEnabled="True"  IsLoadOnDemandEnabled="False"

                                             Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadExpander}, Path=ActualHeight}" 
                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectedElementDataOnlyTemplate}"  Margin="0,0,0,8"              
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedElementsOnly}"  x:Name="ElementsTree2" >
                        </telerik:RadTreeView>

                    </telerik:RadExpander>                  

                </Canvas>
                <telerik:RadTreeView  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ElementPicker" IsExpandOnSingleClickEnabled="True" IsVirtualizing="True"
                             ItemsOptionListType="None" Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ElementDataTemplate}" IsRootLinesEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,8"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}"  IsLoadOnDemandEnabled="True"    Visibility="{Binding ToggleSelectedElements,
                                                                                 Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" LoadOnDemand="tvMain_LoadOnDemand" x:Name="ElementsTree" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}">
                </telerik:RadTreeView>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Canvas instead of Grid does the trick.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further?